# Web container to web api container communication in docker for windows

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm stuck with container to container communication. I've deployed web application and web api in docker for windows. I can access web api directly from browser. I'm calling this using services endpoint in my web application as I studied on the internet but it is not getting connected.

[image]

http://dockerSampleWebApi:8083/weatherforecast/ this is my service endpoint I'm using in my code. dockerSampleWebAPI is service name defined in docker-compose file.

Comment: If you're calling it from a browser, it is _not_ container-to-container to communication: the browser runs outside Docker and needs to reach a published port on the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze : agree. here my main question is how to access webapi container inside web application.